# WPF Draw Lines in a loop only seems to draw one line

Tags: c#, wpf, for-loop

I'm trying to draw several lines to the canvas within a for loop but only seems to be drawing one. What am I doing wrong?

```
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
        {
            Random rand = new Random();
            double newTop = rand.Next(0, 50);


            Line top = new Line();
            top.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
            top.StrokeThickness = 2;
            top.Width = 50;

            top.X1 = x * top.Width;
            top.Y1 = 0;
            top.X2 = x * top.Width + top.Width;
            top.Y2 = newTop;

            Canvas.SetTop(top, 0);
            Canvas.SetLeft(top, x * top.Width);
            TheCanvas.Children.Add(top);
        }
```

thanks,
Tarran

Comment: I added the Random generator to give more of an example that it is not drawing more than one line... I've just moved it outside the loop and it is the same thing... still only one line.

Comment: OK. I've removed the Random generator completely; this is how it was, should draw 9 horizontal lines next to each other, creating what appears as one long line. (Replaced top.Y2 = newTop; with top.Y2 = 0;

Comment: Could you try `top.StrokeThickness = x` to make sure the lines are drown as expected? I'm asking because you set new `top.X1` every time _and_ set `Canvas.SetLeft` to the same value again.

Comment: I've just set `top.StrokeThickness = x` and the line doesn't show (as first x is zero... I set a trace point (`x = {x}`) and shows x is incrementing until 9 so I am completely stumped.

Comment: And if you do `top.StrokeThickness = x`, does it show just one thin line?

Comment: No. it shows no line as the first x is 0, so `top.StrokeThickness = 0`... i'm not sure why it only seems to be running once.

Comment: Sorry, I meant _"And if you do top.StrokeThickness = x + 1, does it show just one thin line?"_

Comment: The issue is that from the second step you are drawing outside of canvas, `top.X1 >= top.Width`.

Comment: I've done that and does show one thin line, the length of `top.Length = 50`... so still appears to draw only once.

Comment: @AlexD - "The issue is that from the second step you are drawing outside of canvas, top.X1 >= top.Width"... this helped a lot... thank you... I misunderstood how Line() worked. I replaced the X1, X2, Y1 and Y2 values and works how expected. 
`top.X1 = 0;
                top.Y1 = 0;
                top.X2 = top.Width;
                top.Y2 = 0;`

Comment: @DungeonMaster3000 - When commenting on an answer please put the comment under the answer, not the question. Also, when replying to someone you should include the `@ user name` tag (without the spaces) to send a notification to the recipient and to allow others to follow the thread of the conversation. Cheers. :-)

Answer (score 4):

You may get the same value from random generator every time:

> The default seed value is derived from the system clock and has finite resolution. As a result, different Random objects that are created in close succession by a call to the default constructor will have identical default seed values and, therefore, will produce identical sets of random numbers."

See [Random Constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h343ddh9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

I'd suggest to move the line

```
Random rand = new Random();
```

in front of the loop.

---

Also, it seems that from the second step you are drawing outside of canvas. Try the following code instead:

```
Random rand = new Random();
for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
{
    double newTop = rand.Next(0, 50);

    Line top = new Line();
    top.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
    top.StrokeThickness = x + 1;
    top.Width = 500;

    int width = 50;
    top.X1 = x * width;
    top.Y1 = 0;
    top.X2 = x * width + width;
    top.Y2 = newTop;

    Canvas.SetTop(top, 0);
    Canvas.SetLeft(top, 0 /*x * top.Width*/);
    TheCanvas.Children.Add(top);
}
```

Comment: "The issue is that from the second step you are drawing outside of canvas, top.X1 >= top.Width"... this helped a lot... thank you... I misunderstood how Line() worked. I replaced the X1, X2, Y1 and Y2 values and works how expected. `top.X1 = 0; top.Y1 = 0; top.X2 = top.Width; top.Y2 = 0;`

Answer (score 0):

You're drawing the same line over and over, you need to seed the random number with something different.

```
Random rand = new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode());
```

Your other option is to move the random creation outside of your loop, and use `Next`, like you have. I'd suggest using this option:

```
Random rand = new Random();

for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
    {
        double newTop = rand.Next(0, 50);

        Line top = new Line();
        top.Stroke = Brushes.Black;
        top.StrokeThickness = 2;
        top.Width = 50;

        top.X1 = x * top.Width;
        top.Y1 = 0;
        top.X2 = x * top.Width + top.Width;
        top.Y2 = newTop;

        Canvas.SetTop(top, 0);
        Canvas.SetLeft(top, x * top.Width);
        TheCanvas.Children.Add(top);
    }
```

This will prevent the `Random` from being re-seeded every time.